# Kill a Ruby child process when another Ruby child process has completed

Tags: android, ruby, process, stress-testing, monkey

I'm trying to use Ruby to write a script to run monkey test on the Android app.  I'm stuck with 1.8 Ruby and can't use spawn.

See below code for detail. For some reasons, the `logcat` process will continue to run even after the `monkey` process has completed. I had used `Process.wait()` for wait for `monkey` process to completed before killing the `logcat` process, but it doesn't kill it. Am I not using the `fork` properly?

Thanks.

```
pid_logcat = fork do
    puts "Enter capturing logcat"
    system("adb shell logcat | tee logcat.log")
end

pid_monkey = fork do
    puts "Running monkey script"
    system("adb shell monkey -p TestApp --throttle 200 -v 1000000 | tee Monkeylog.txt")
end


Process.wait(pid_monkey)
Process.kill("KILL", pid_logcat)
```

**EDITED 1**

I can confirm that `adb` does spawn another process which is outside of ruby's control, what should I do now? `Process.kill('HUP', -Process.getpgid(pid_logcat))` won't work because that will kill the parent process too (the ruby process forking this)

**EDITED 2**
`exec()` also doesn't seem to work on `pid_logcat` forked process.

Comment: Try using exec instead of system to launch those processes.  You're sending a kill to the ruby process and not to adb directly.  I'm not familiar with how adb runs, but if its doing its own forking or playing around with sessions, it will evade that kill signal.

Comment: Thanks Catnapper, but at least the logic seems to be correct right? And using it seems to be correct right?

Comment: Your approach is correct, but it sounds like you will need to find the pid of adb's child process.  Does adb have an option for writing a pidfile?

Comment: This child process of the adb instance - is its parent pid 1, or is it the pid of a parent adb process?  If its the parent pid, you can determine which adb child belongs to each adb parent, and send kills to them.  If the parent pid is 1, that means it is daemonized and there is no easy way to determine which adb was the parent.  If this is the case, you might consider a shotgun approach of killing all adb processes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `Process.wait(pid_logcat)` after your code.

Comment: It just works. Wait doesn't wait for logcat to finish, but it just 'join' it after kill.